# Why does List.Sum() perform poorly as compared to a foreach?

Tags: c#, performance, foreach, sum

Question: Why does the execution time of `Sum()` take much longer than a `foreach()` in the following scenario?

```
public void TestMethod4()
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add(i);
    }

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    long totalCount = numbers.Sum(num => true ? 1 : 0); // simulating a dummy true condition
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time taken Sum() : {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    totalCount = 0;
    foreach (var num in numbers)
    {
        totalCount += true ? 1 : 0; // simulating a dummy true condition
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Time taken foreach() : {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Sample run1

```
Time taken Sum()     : 21443.8093ms
Time taken foreach() : 4251.9795ms
```

Comment: You’re using `new Random` incorrectly.

Comment: Was this a debug build or a release build? And how is your program not crashing due to divide-by-zero?

Comment: @Dai, it is not dividing but adding a 0 in the Sum function.

Comment: "I found that the Sum() is actually slower as compared to a foreach" -- why would that be a surprise?

Comment: I found the issue when running some performance numbers in the release build. I think in my case the condition is always being evaluated to true hence the function was consuming extra time. I am curious to see why the time difference is the same when it is a random boolean eveluation.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking - indeed `foreach` is consistently faster by about the same fixed time... which is shown in your results... Could you please clarify if the fact more complicated method (`Sum`) is slower need explanation or something else. Please also use `Random` correctly (so it actually generates random result) and [edit] question with these clarifications.

Comment: Use Benchmark dotnet for Performance analysation of code. https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Comment: What is the question?  I don't see where you are asking anything.  This looks like a blog post.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. I am curious to see why `Sum` is slower when the condition evaluates to only true or false as seen from the perf numbers.

Comment: I don't think that your foreach loop is doing all the same things that Sum has to do.  Specifically, I don't see the convert from bool to number and looks like the false case is missing the addition

Comment: @Mike it doesn't matter. But I have updated the code and perf numbers for you.

Comment: the hardcoded true/false will be getting some compile time help (over calling through the functor in Sum())  which probably explains most of the different for the hardcoded cases.

Comment: Hardcoded values really don't matter. I was seeing the result from my release build where the condition was always getting evaluated to true. Even here we are calling the function repeatedly and there is no caching.

Comment: you could try calling through a Func<> instead like sum has to do.  This would remove some of the compile time win and would more closely mimic Sum()

Comment: @DevendraLattu I think the closed votes are because there is a lot of confusion about the use of Rand().  I don't believe that Rand() is really relevant to your question so if you can remove it from the sample, then maybe we can re-open this question.

Comment: @DevendraLattualso, I haven't tried it locally but I really do think you are just seeing the compile time optimizations in play in the foreach case.  Looking at the byte code would show you the differences

Comment: Your list is reallocated a number of times. Make sure the GC is does not kick in when you run `Sum()` (with hidden allocations). You should pre-allocate your list with a capacity of `1000000000` to avoid this gotcha.

Comment: @l33t yep, I intentionally left it that way as it did not have any impact on the readings.

Comment: Well, to me it is totally clear that you will get a GC when `Sum()` *allocates* its enumerator. So either your readings are inaccurate or you were lucky on that particular run. On my machine, I can't even run this method due to the enormous amount of memory needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The difference in times is caused by the CLR applying two separate optimizations in the second case, but not the first case:

- Linq's `Sum` operates on `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>`.

  - The CLR/JIT *does* have a special-case optimization for `foreach` with `List<T>`, but not if a `List<T>` is passed as `IEnumerable<T>`.

    - Which means it's using `IEnumerator<T>` and incurring the cost of all of virtual-calls associated with that.
    - Whereas using `List<T>` directly uses static calls (instance method calls are still "static" calls, provided they're not virtual).
- Linq's `Sum` accepts a delegate `Func<T,Int64>`.

  - Functions passed as a delegate `Func<T,Int64>` are not inlined, even with `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInline`.
  - The cost of a delegate invocation are *slightly* more expensive than virtual calls.

---

I've reimplemented your `SUM` program using a variety of different approaches which you access here: https://gist.github.com/Jehoel/1a4fcd2e70374d3694c3a105061a6d1c

My benchmark results (Release build, x64, .NET Core 5, i7-7700HQ):

| Approach | Time (ms) |
| --- | --- |
| Test_Sum_Delegate | 118ms |
| Test_MySum_DirectFunc_IEnum | 112ms |
| Test_MySum_IndirectFunc_IEnum | 114ms |
| Test_MySum_DirectCall_IEnum | 89ms |
| Test_MySum_DirectFunc_List | 58ms |
| Test_MySum_IndirectFunc_List | 58ms |
| Test_MySum_DirectCall_List | 37ms |
| Test_Sum_DelegateLambda | 109ms |
| Test_For_Inline | 4ms |
| Test_For_Delegate | 3ms |
| Test_ForUnrolled_Inline | 4ms |
| Test_ForUnrolled_Delegate | 4ms |
| Test_ForEach_Inline | 38ms |
| Test_ForEach_Delegate | 37ms |

We can isolate the different behaviour by changing one thing at a time (e.g. `foreach` vs `for`, `IEnumerable<T>` vs `List<T>`, `Func<T>` vs direct function calls).

The `System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum` approach (`Test_Sum_Delegate`) is identical to `Test_MySum_IndirectFunc_IEnum` (disregard the `4ms` difference between them). Both of these approaches iterate over the `List<T>` using `IEnumerable<T>`.

Changing the method to pass the `List<T>` as a `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` (in `Test_MySum_IndirectFunc_List`) eliminates the virtual-calls from `foreach` using `IEnumerator<T>` which causes a reduction from `~114ms` to `58ms`, a 50% reduction in time already.

Then changing the `Func<Int64,Int64>` (a delegate) call to the `GetValue` func to a "static" call to `GetValue` (as in `Test_MySum_DirectCall_List`) brings the time down to `37ms` - which is the same as `Test_ForEach_Delegate`. This approach is the same as your hand-written `foreach` loop.

The only way to get faster performance is with a `for` loop without any virtual calls. (In debug builds the Unrolled loop is even faster than the normal `for` loop, but in Release builds there's no observed difference).